# how to group foreignkey values from a queryset in django

Tags: django

I have tow models as follows:

```
class site(models.Model):
    siteId = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    siteName = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class directions(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    siteInfo = models.ForeignKey(site)
```

there are two sites and each site has two directions.The result I want is a list with two element, each represent a site with two directions grouped as list. something like:

```
[{"siteId":1,"siteName":baba,"siteInfo":[{"name":"xx","direction":"south"},{"name":"yy","direction":"north"},]]
```

I tried:

```
print list(site.objects.all().values('siteName','siteId','directions__direction','directions__name'))
```

but the result is a list of four items

Comment: You should capitalize your model names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try prefetch_related and list comprehensions:

```
[{
    "siteId": site.siteId, 
    "siteName": site.siteName, 
    "siteInfo": [{
        "name": siteInfo.name, 
        "direction": siteInfo.direction
     } for siteInfo in site.directions_set.all()]
} for site in Site.objects.prefetch_related('directions_set')]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the related name be something like 'directions', not 'siteInfos' ?

Comment: Sure, although it's not quite consistent in the question.  I actually took out the related_name and just used the default "directions_set".